# Way of Ordering a ranked list

Tags: order-theory, order-statistics

I am trying to find a good way of ordering and ranking a list of objects.

They will be ranked multiple times by different people but i want their rank (out of 10) to update.

e.g I rank the objects like so (bracket is current rank based on 10 previous opinions):

Apples (1) > Oranges (2) > Pears (3) > Grapes (4) > Bananas (3) > Strawberries (1)

I want to update my ranks based on this new opinion.

Sorry if the question is a  bit vague i haven't done any Mathematics in half a decade but would like a decent starting point of something to look at that can assist me. Of the top of my head i was just going to do something like:

1. Calculate mean
2. Calculate standard deviation
3. Add/subtract the standard deviation from the mean in multiples of qty step up / down. This then gives that users rank.
4. Update rank based on new users rankings of  objects (not sure how to weight this)

This just seems to spread the new ranking out to much however and was hoping for some advice as there must be some clever way of doing this properly.